# Create ArrayList in one step

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, arraylist, enums

I'm desperately trying to **create** an **ArrayList** out of objects of an enumeration **in one step** in *C# with Visual Studio 2012*.
It should look like something of the following:

```
new ArrayList( {class1.enum.sample1, class1.enum.sample2, class1.enum.sample3} );
```

When I'm writing it in two lines, it works:

```
class1.enum[] array = {class1.enum.sample1, class1.enum.sample2, class1.enum.sample3};
ArrayList test = new ArrayList(ha);
```

But I need to write it in one line. Could you help me, please?

Comment: why you want to do this ? why no use enum directly ?

Comment: what is the variable ha?

Comment: @AliUmair: maybe the list should store only part of all enum values.

Answer (score 2):

You need another collection like an array to be able to use the [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var al = new ArrayList { new[] { class1.enum.sample1, class1.enum.sample2, class1.enum.sample3 } };
```

But there is no reason to use the old `ArrayList` anymore. In this case you could use a `List<class1.enum>` (apart from the fact that `enum` is a keyword).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need parenthesis `()` for array list initializer. You can initialize in a single line as under.

```
ArrayList test = new ArrayList{class1.enum.sample1, class1.enum.sample2, class1.enum.sample3}
```

Array list should be replace with generic list unless you have solid reason to use Arraylist. You can find more about using generic list in [Benefits of Generics on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b5bx6xee(v=vs.80).aspx)